# Como mantener el mismo alto en las columnas con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una modal que envia un formulario, si el backend devuelve un error de validacion se mostrara un mensaje debajo del input correspondiente. Cuando no existe ningun error todo se ve alineado pero cuando en algun input hay error todo se descuadra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="row d-flex">
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0"
            for="primer_nombre_acu">Primer
         nombre</label>
         <input id="primer_nombre_acu" type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="primer_nombre_acu">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0"
            for="primer_apellido_acu">Primer
         apellido</label>
         <input id="primer_apellido_acu" type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="primer_apellido_acu">
      </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="col-6 border-left border-light">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0"
            for="segundo_nombre_acu">Segundo
         nombre</label>
         <input id="segundo_nombre_acu" type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="segundo_nombre_acu">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0"
            for="segundo_apellido_acu">Segundo
         apellido</label>
         <input id="segundo_apellido_acu" type="text"
            class="form-control"
            name="segundo_apellido_acu">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Y el mensaje de error lo coloco con jQuery de la siguiente forma

```
$("#"+field_name").after('<span class="error text-danger">'+error+'</span>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema radica mas en el orden de la estructura, porque incluso creo asi te daria problemas de funcionalidad, por ejemplo si ahora te posicionas en el Primer Nombre y das TAB te va a mandar a Primer Apellido , despues a Segundo Nombre y despues a Segundo Apellido. y en el caso de pasar a resoluciones mas bajas se te acomodaria asi

- Primer Nombre
- Primer Apellido
- Segundo Nombre
- Segundo Apellido

Bueno, el detalle es que creo es mas cosa de estructura. yo como recomendacion lo haria asi

```
<div class="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="primer_nombre_acu">Primer nombre</label>
                <input id="primer_nombre_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="primer_nombre_acu">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="segundo_nombre_acu">Segundo nombre</label>
                <input id="segundo_nombre_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="segundo_nombre_acu">
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="primer_apellido_acu">Primer apellido</label>
                <input id="primer_apellido_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="primer_apellido_acu">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="segundo_apellido_acu">Segundo apellido</label>
                <input id="segundo_apellido_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="segundo_apellido_acu">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

porque asi agrupas primer y segundo nombre en la misma division, por tanto ambos van a tomar la misma altura en ese espacio cuando pongas el span, bajando automaticamente los inputs en la otra division y quedando "alineados" y aparte la funcionalidad con el TAB ahora seria Primer Nombre > Segundo Nombre > Primer Apellido > Segundo Apellido

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto:

```js
field_name = "primer_nombre_acu"
error = "Este campo es requerido"
$("#"+field_name).after('<span class="error text-danger">'+error+'</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="primer_nombre_acu">Primer
        nombre</label>
      <input id="primer_nombre_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="primer_nombre_acu">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 border-left border-light">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="segundo_nombre_acu">Segundo
        nombre</label>
      <input id="segundo_nombre_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="segundo_nombre_acu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="primer_apellido_acu">Primer
      apellido</label>
    <input id="primer_apellido_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="primer_apellido_acu">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 border-left border-light">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold d-block my-0" for="segundo_apellido_acu">Segundo
      apellido</label>
    <input id="segundo_apellido_acu" type="text" class="form-control" name="segundo_apellido_acu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aunque la explicación ya te la ha dado @StialManstike, pero se asemeja más a lo que tenias. (no aceptes mi respuesta! Acepta la de el, yo aún estaba peleándome con el código y así me ahorro la explicación)